# how to transfer the file via Bluetooth from windows to android using c++ socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets, uwp, bluetooth

I'm trying to write the C++ code in order to transfer a text file from Desktop to phone via Bluetooth given the device paired

```cpp
Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformationCollection services{
    co_await Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(
        Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Rfcomm::RfcommDeviceService::GetDeviceSelector(
            Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Rfcomm::RfcommServiceId::ObexObjectPush()))
    };
   
    // Initialize the target Bluetooth BR device.
    Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Rfcomm::RfcommDeviceService service{
        co_await Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Rfcomm::RfcommDeviceService::FromIdAsync(services.GetAt(0).Id()) };
       
    // Check that the service meets this App's minimum
    // requirement
     
    m_service = service;

    printf("Connection name %ls \n", m_service.ConnectionHostName().DisplayName().c_str());
    printf("Service name %ls \n ", m_service.ConnectionServiceName().c_str());
    printf("Current Status %d \n ", m_service.DeviceAccessInformation().CurrentStatus());
           
    // Create a socket and connect to the target
    co_await m_socket.ConnectAsync(
        m_service.ConnectionHostName(),
        m_service.ConnectionServiceName(),
        Windows::Networking::Sockets::SocketProtectionLevel::BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);
```

Now socket is connected to android device I want to transfer the file using Socket API can anyone please help me to transfer the file via Bluetooth in windows.

i am referring to the link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm

Comment: By default modern smartphones (ncluding Android devices) have OBEX Object Push profile. So your application must run as OPP client to be able to send files.

Comment: i tried pushing obexobject push but I'm unable to get how to transfer a fail

Comment: And how did you try it?

Comment: Referring The MSDN I tried to use ObexObjectPush But I'm not getting how to transfer the file using socket API . And also should I need to run the code on both client and server

Comment: You mean the link in your question? There is nothing about OBEX. Here is the OBEX spec: https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/ext-ref/IrDA/OBEX15.pdf

Comment: i have already used 
Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Rfcomm::RfcommServiceId::ObexObjectPush()                             Please let me know, if there is any direct example i can refer

Comment: Its services UUID. It does nothing regarding protocol itself (see the link I posted early). You must implement the OBEX protocol first. At least mandatory operations (OPEN SESSION, PUT, ABORT, CLOSE SESSION) defined in OPP Profile.

Comment: Direct example? This should be OK: https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/tree/main/InTheHand.Net.Obex

Comment: Or use third party libraries: 32 feet, Bluetooth Framework, other can be found in Internet.